# CSS fixed sidebar & Headbar with content

Tags: html, css

How can I get a fixed Header with a fixed Sidebar and a Content Div?

What i did so far:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #303030;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 38px 133px;
    height: 40px;
    background-position: 0px 39px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.sidebar {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #303030;
}

.content {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 810px;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

But at the moment it's not stable and a bit weird. Means for example that the Content Div is floating under my sidebar and else.

Does someone know a better and more effective was to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think it will help you, For u'r understanding i have added red border for content div. Only I changed the CSS.

    `.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    right: 0px;
}`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #303030;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 38px 133px;
    height: 40px;
    background-position: 0px 39px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.sidebar {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #303030;
}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are minor changes in your CSS like:

```
.content {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 810px;
    min-height: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.header{top:0}
```

This will do the trick. If not please comment.